# jQuery plugin access

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I'm doing a youtube player in jQuery, and I make this as a jQuery plugin, ex:

```
 $.fn.extend({

        uplayList: {},

        CreateUplayList: function (options) {
            this.each(function  () {
                $(this).uplayList = new $.playList(this, options);
            });
        }
    });
```

But, if I do:

```
$('#playlist').CreateUplayList({....});
```

And I want access at the instance:

```
$('#playlist').uplayList.play();
```

This not work, that make sense, because $('#playlist') is a selector. I see in others plugins something like that:

```
$('#playlist').pluginname('play');
```

How can I apply this??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the "Adding Methods to a Widget" section of the "Stateful Plugins" section of the [jQuery Plugin Authoring Guide](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/stateful-plugins-with-widget-factory/).

Comment: +1 Oh, and @Exos always remember... "jQuery.fn is pronounced jQuery effin' "

Comment: whel, so dont me aswer to. I do it: http://pastebin.com/TDLFLh6V and now $('#obj').UplayList('play'); or $('#obj').UplayList('setVolume',75); works! using data i save the id of the player (unique and generated on runtime). Thx!

Comment: I see no "methods section" and the only mention of "stateful plugin" (which seems to be what the OP was searching for) is in the [jQuery UI Widget Factory section](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/stateful-plugins-with-widget-factory/) which didn't me

Comment: @PierredeLESPINAY they seem to have rewritten that guide :(

Comment: That's what I thought too. Still searching for a non jQuery UI dependent solution.